# Incorrect results from numeric comparison in R

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I wish to perform this simple categorization on a data frame in R. The categories are 1,2,3,4, and -1. I wish to add the results of this calculation to a new column in the data frame. "oldCol" is the name of a column already in the data frame.

```
DF$newCol <- apply(DF, 1, function(row) {
    if (row[["oldCol"]] > 10.0)
    {result1 <- 4.0}
    else if (row[["oldCol"]] > 2.0 && row[["oldCol"]] <= 10.0) 
    {result1 <- 3.0}
    else if (row[["oldCol"]] > 0.5 && row[["oldCol"]] <= 2.0) 
    {result1 <- 2.0}
    else if (row[["oldCol"]] > 0.0 && row[["oldCol"]] <= 0.5) 
    {result1 <- 1.0}
    else
    {result1 <- -1.0}
    return(result1)
})
```

My problem: the code does make a new column, but the values in it are incorrect! With this exact code, numbers over 10 are correctly classified as class 4, but all other rows contain -1. Why? The algorithm is so simple that this is really bothering me.

Also, is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: `apply` will convert your rows to vectors, so if your `DF` has character columns, everything will be converted to character... For example `apply(data.frame(x = 1:26, y = letters), 1, function(row)class(row[["x"]]))` returns "character", not "integer".

Comment: Thanks, Ben Bolker! This solved my problem:

Comment: keepData <- transform(keepData,
        SizeClass4=as.numeric(as.character(cut(LeafArea,
          breaks=c(-Inf,0,0.5,2,10,Inf),
          labels=c(-1,1:4)))))

Comment: I didn't think to check the data type inside my if statements, but apparently apply was acting differently than I expected! Thanks flodel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works for me:

```
DF <- data.frame(oldCol=c(-1,0.25,1,5,12))

DF$newCol <- apply(DF, 1, function(row) {
    if (row[["oldCol"]] > 10.0)
    {result1 <- 4.0}
    else if (row[["oldCol"]] > 2.0 && row[["oldCol"]] <= 10.0) 
    {result1 <- 3.0}
    else if (row[["oldCol"]] > 0.5 && row[["oldCol"]] <= 2.0) 
    {result1 <- 2.0}
    else if (row[["oldCol"]] > 0.0 && row[["oldCol"]] <= 0.5) 
    {result1 <- 1.0}
    else
    {result1 <- -1.0}
    return(result1)
})
```

Results:

```
##   oldCol newCol
## 1  -1.00     -1
## 2   0.25      1
## 3   1.00      2
## 4   5.00      3
## 5  12.00      4
##
```

One alternative:

```
DF <- transform(DF,
        newCol=as.numeric(as.character(cut(oldCol,
          breaks=c(-Inf,0,0.5,2,10,Inf),
          labels=c(-1,1:4)))))
```

or:

```
library("plyr")
DF <- mutate(DF,
        tmpCol=cut(oldCol,
           breaks=c(-Inf,0,0.5,2,10,Inf),labels=FALSE),
        newCol=ifelse(tmpCol=="1",-1,as.numeric(tmpCol)-1))
```

Comment: Yes, when I run your example code on my machine it works properly. However, the other data frame I was working on originally is much larger, 10,000x11 dimensions. What would cause it to work improperly? I checked the mode and class of my data frame columns and they are all numeric . . . can't figure out why the simple example works but not my other data frame?

Comment: Thanks by the way for verifying my algorithm, I was worried that I was doing something terribly wrong. I'm going to update with a few more details about my data frame.

Comment: And I'm going to try those other suggestions. I am not familiar with transform very much, but I'll try it.

Comment: @mad-hay: you need to see whether you can boil the problem down to something manageable that still demonstrates the problem.  For example (1) do you still get the same problem if you apply your code to a dataframe consisting of just the `oldCol` column? (2) do you still get the same problem if you apply your code to just `head(DF)` (the first few rows) or `tail(DF)` (the last few rows)?  What are the results of `summary(DF)` or `str(DF)`?

Comment: I checked the mode and class of the temporary variable "row" inside the apply function, and as flodel said, the entire row was a character vector! Thanks guys for helping me solve this!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a somewhat simpler answer that also takes into account that you're dealing with `double`'s, and so will have precision issues:

```
cuts = c(0, 0.5, 2, 10) + 1e-8 # example precision, pick appropriately for your problem
                               # (possibly pick a different precision for each cut point)
DF$newCol = findInterval(DF$oldCol, cuts)
```

Comment: This is nice, but you do still need to map the lowest category from 0 to -1 (e.g. `DF$newcol[DF$newcol==0] <- -1`)

Comment: @BenBolker agreed, if that's really imperative